# How to align contents from fragment 's xml file with the content's from it's parent activity's xml file in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I have this activity_main xml file and fragment_easy.xml file which is
related to EasyFragment present in the the Activity itself. So, the
fragment contains the Toolbar and in activity, I have put my
TabLayout. But my screen looks like this[image] I want my TabLayout below my Toolbar. I want the TabLayout to be vertical and connected to left side of the screen.

Below is the code of my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- FragmentContainerView for Navigation -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

    <!-- TabLayout Container -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <!-- TabLayout -->
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            android:rotation="-90"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- ViewPager2 -->
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayoutContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the code for my fragment's layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeFlashcard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back_icon"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Easy"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtext_flash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Pick a set to practice"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is code for flash_tablebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#7bd596"
        android:centerColor="#71d29c"
        android:endColor="#49c5ac"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="45dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp" />
</shape>
```